# How to store a list of linked lists in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Consider a number of `Linked List` in `C`. As shown in the following code:

```
struct path {
int node;
struct path *next;
};
```

I want to have a lot of this linked list. How can I have it? For example:

> 1, 2, 3
>
> 1, 5, 6
>
> 1, 3, 5, 7

These are three instances of my Linked list and I need to store them with their size in a list.

So, I do not know how to I can have many instances of the Linked list and store them into a list (Should I use another Linked list?).

Comment: Google for "adjacency matrix"

Comment: @MichaelWalz I know Adj. Matrix and Adj. List. I used of CSR representation to store the graph.

Comment: Then what's wrong with CSR?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I use of CSR to discover my graph. I want to find some paths and store them on a list.

Comment: Sorry, the question is too broad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167185/discussion-between-saeed-rahmani-and-michael-walz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `struct path` is a linked list of integers.  If you want a list of paths, you can define that too:

```
struct path_list {
    struct path *path;
    int path_size;  /* optional: a place to store the size of "path" rather than recomputing it all the time */
    struct path_list *next;
};
```

---

To use any kind of linked list, you generally want to define functions to allocate/free/manipulate/query lists.  So you might have

```
struct path *new_path_el(int node, struct path *next) {
    struct path *rv = malloc(sizeof(struct path));
    rv->node = node;
    rv->next = next;
    return rv; }
int path_size(struct path *path) {
    int rv = 0;
    while (path) {
        ++rv;
        path = path->next; }
    return rv; }
struct path_list *new_path_list_el(struct path *path, struct path_list *next) {
    struct path_list *rv = malloc(sizeof(struct path_list));
    rv->path = path;
    rv->path_size = path_size(path);
    rv->next = next;
    return rv; }
```

Which allows you to create your example above:

```
new_path_list_el(
    new_path_el(1, new_path_el(2, new_path_el(3, 0))),
  new_path_list_el(
      new_path_el(1, new_path_el(5, new_path_el(6, 0))),
    new_path_list_el(
        new_path_el(1, new_path_el(3, new_path_el(5, new_path_el(7, 0)))), 0)))
```

Comment: Is it possible to sort the path_list based on size?

Comment: how to I can print the lists? does not it need the head and tail pointer?